# Count unknown variables from a table

Tags: variables, lua, count, lua-table

I have a problem here... if I have a table with few repeated string  results. I want to know the value am the ammount of each.
For example. A function return an unknown "letters" and with unknown quantities in quantity

```
Function () return Table end
Table ={'a','a','c','b','b','a',...}
```

And I want to get this.

```
table.a={'a','a','a'}
table.b={'b','b'}
table.c={'c'}
....
....
```

I have no clue how to solve it...

Comment: Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2):

Write a function, which creates a hash map of these things:

```
function RepetitionCounter(tInput)
    local tCounter = {}
    for i, v in ipairs(tInput) do
        tCounter[v] = (tCounter[v] or 0) + 1
    end
    return tCounter
end
```

which you'll use as follows:

```
local tData = {'a','a','c','b','b','a',...}
local tCounts = RepetitionCounter(tData)
```

and the table `tCounts` would be as follows:

```
tCounts.a = 3
tCounts.b = 2
tCounts.c = 1
```

---

Modifying the function above by just a little, you can get the desired output. Replace the following line:

```
tCounter[v] = (tCounter[v] or 0) + 1
```

with

```
if not tCounter[v] then
    tCounter[v] = {}
else
    table.insert(tCounter[v], v)
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't "tCounter[v] = (tCounter[v] and tCounter[v] + 1) or 0" be "tCounter[v] = (tCounter[v] or 0) + 1"?

Comment: @tonypdmtr Thanks! Updated. =)